# Can Kafka be used as a messaging service between oracle and elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, oracle-golden-gate

Can Kafka be used as a messaging service between oracle and elastic search ? any downsides of this approach?

Comment: You will need to provide more details on your problem and aims.

Comment: https://jgtree420.wordpress.com/2017/03/13/kafka-connect-jdbc-oracle-example/

Answer (score 2):

[**Kafka Connect**](https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/) provides you a [JDBC Source](https://www.confluent.io/blog/streaming-data-oracle-using-oracle-goldengate-kafka-connect/) and an [Elasticsearch Sink](https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-1/).

No downsides that I am aware of, other than service maintenance.

Feel free to use Logstash instead, but [Kafka provides better resiliency](https://www.confluent.io/blog/okay-store-data-apache-kafka/) and scalability.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this in the past with Sql server instead of Oracle and it works great, and I am sure you could try the same approach with Oracle as well since I know the logstash JDBC plugin that I am going to describe below has support for Oracle DB.

So basically you would need a Logstash JDBC input plugin https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html that points to your Oracle DB instance and pushes the rows over to Kafka using the Kafka Output plugin https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-kafka.html.

Now to read the contents from Kafka you would need, another Logstash instance(*this is the indexer*) and use the Kafka input plugin https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-kafka.html. And finally use the Elastic search output plugin in the Logstash indexer configuration file to push the events to Elastic Search.

So the pipeline would look like this, 
**Oracle -> Logstash Shipper -> Kafka -> Logstash Indexer -> Elastic search**.

So overall I think this is a pretty scalable way to push events from your DB to Elastic search. Now, if you look at downsides, at times you can feel that there are one too many components in your pipeline and can be frustrating especially when you have failures. So you need to put in appropriate controls and monitoring at every level to make sure you have a functioning data aggregation pipeline that is described above.  Give it a try and good luck!

Comment: You can cut Logstash out of that pipeline and just use Kafka tools.

Comment: if you are going to use the logstash jdbc plgin, look for sql_last_value in the documentation, you would need a timestamp field in your table and that should get updated with modified date timestamp